# Cant see video of other person in twilio

Tags: java, android, twilio

I am trying to create a video calling app,when i connect to a room i can see my video, i can see the other persons video, but the other person cant see me.i have added the localaudiotracks,localvideotracks but still no success. here us the snippet

```
ConnectOptions connectOptions = new ConnectOptions.Builder(token)
            .roomName(roomName)
            .videoTracks(Collections.singletonList(localVideoTrack))
            .audioTracks(Collections.singletonList(localAudioTrack))
            .enableInsights(true)
            .enableNetworkQuality(true)
            .build();
    room = Video.connect(this, connectOptions, roomListener());
```

also i tried to use `room.publishTrack(localVideoTrack)`
still did not have success.

**Note** - i can see hear both of the oter person, the other person cant see me but can hear me
I am using Twilio 6.1.0

One more thing i tried there sample app with my room name and token there its working fine, please let me know what i am missing.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm hitting the same issue

Comment: check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68064272/10575326

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so in the docs it was not mentioned properly. And after researching a lot and doing hit and trial I got to the solution.
When creating the localvideotrack we need to pass what we need to show the camera or the screen. So I created a string

```
private String CAMERA = "camera";
```

Then called it when creating the track -

```
Camera1Enumerator camera1Enumerator = new Camera1Enumerator();
if (camera1Enumerator.getDeviceNames() != null) {
            for (String cameraId : camera1Enumerator.getDeviceNames()) {
                if (camera1Enumerator.isBackFacing(cameraId)) {
                    backCameraId = cameraId;
                }
                if (!camera1Enumerator.isBackFacing(cameraId)) {
                    frontCameraId = cameraId;
                }
            }
            cameraCapturer = new CameraCapturer(this, frontCameraId);
            localVideoTrack = LocalVideoTrack.create(this, true, cameraCapturer, new VideoFormat(VideoDimensions.HD_720P_VIDEO_DIMENSIONS, 30), CAMERA); // here we pass it
```

And then pass this as it is in

```
ConnectOptions connectOptions = new ConnectOptions.Builder(token)
        .roomName(roomName)
        .videoTracks(Collections.singletonList(localVideoTrack))
        .audioTracks(Collections.singletonList(localAudioTrack))
        .enableInsights(true)
        .enableNetworkQuality(true)
        .build();
room = Video.connect(this, connectOptions, roomListener());
```